# How to init SelectItemsIndexConverter's index?

Tags: jsf, selectonemenu, omnifaces

I am using [Omnifaces' SelectItemsIndexConverter](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/converters/SelectItemsIndexConverter) and it works like a charm.
But when I need to edit an existing entity then I want the selectOneMenu to show up the right entry when loading the page. Currently it always shows up the first entry (index 0) as selected entry.

I need to set the right initial index value for SelectItemsIndexConverter, right? How can I achieve that?

Comment: How would you do it without the converter? It should not be different when using a converter.

Comment: With an "ordinary" converter the right element from "selectOneMenu" is preselected because of the value attribute of the selectOneMenu.
How should the SelectItemsIndexConverter know which select-entry corresponds to the initial value of complex type?

Comment: Maybe I should add some code later to the question ...

Comment: It knows that just the same way as any other converter.

Comment: I've to make a stripped code sample for that question. My original code here is too complex for this question with an composite component etc.

I am sure you'll be right at the end like always with JSF and especially for code that you wrote yourself. Maybe I've messed something up ...